# Joining two tables and linking the third table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to do a left join on the following two tables and link it with another table

for eg.
I have a table called **students**

```
SID (pk) 
fname 
lname
```

**assignment table**

```
aid (pk)
dur 
SID (fk) 
pid (fk)
```

**professor table**

```
pid (pk) 
pname
```

I will take `fname` from **first table** and `pid` from **second table** `left join` them and display corresponding `pname` from `professor table`.

So i want the table to look like this later

```
Fname Pname   

Raju  Jack 
RAm   Null  
jim   john
```

Thanks

I have written the code like this but it is not working

```sql
select students.fname, professor.pname
from student

LEFT JOIN professor ON professor.pid = assignment.pid
```

i want to do left join so i will get fname and pid , but instead i want to use pid to get pname and display fname and pname

Comment: What problem are you having? We're not going to write it for you, but we'll help you fix your code.

Comment: I have left joined the student and assignment table
so now i have <br>
fname pid  <br>
raju      012 <br>
ram    null <br>
jim       025 <br>

So i now want to use the pid and find pname in professor table and only display fname and pname

Comment: Just add `LEFT JOIN professor ON professor.pid = assignment.pid`.

Comment: u mean like this ?
<br>
select students.fname, professor.pname <br>
from student <br>
<br>
LEFT JOIN professor ON professor.pid = assignment.pid <br>

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question to show what you tried. If it's not working, explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing if you want output like this.
Instead of using left join you can use simply join.
I have checked it out so try this code.

```sql
select s.fname, p.p_name 
from students s  
join assignment a on s.s_id = a.s_id 
join professor p on a.p_id = p.p_id
```

Hope you will get right result.

Comment: If you look at the expected result (`RAm   Null`), you will see that OP needs a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I was hoping to create a view of assignment and professor tables with columns aid, sid, pname and combining them as assignment.pid=professor.pid .

Later I would use left join of student table on the view ....

What do you guys think ? Please chime in your thoughts ....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to create a view of assignment and professor tables with columns aid, sid, pname and combining them as assignment.pid=professor.pid .

Later I would use left join of student table on the view ....

What do you guys think ? Please chime in your thoughts ....
Thanks